# How to insert algorithm pseudocode in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, algorithms

recently I found `LyX` is good for writing notes. But I don't know how to add a piece of algorithm pseudocode in Lyx environment. Could you please help give some advice? Thanks!

How could I implement the following algorithmic pseudocode? Could you please give the complete operations on `LyX 2.1.1`?

[image]

Comment: @scottkosty,thank you for improving the post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have found the answer:

1. add the `\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}` into the premble
2. insert a algorithm block (Insert --> Floating --> Algorithm)
3. insert the tex code in the algorithm block (Insert --> Tex Code)
4. add the following latex code

   ```
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \Require{$\rho \geq 1$}
   \Ensure{$X_k$}
   \While{not converged}
   \State{Solve $X_{k+1}=\min_{X} L(X,Y_k, \mu_k)$}
   \State{$Y_{k+1}=Y_k+\mu_k h(X_{k+1})$}
   \State{$\mu_{k+1}=\rho \mu_k$}
   \EndWhile
   \end{algorithmic}
   ```

Comment: Do you need to use raw latex in this inside block or can you use lyx formatting?

Comment: Hi, yes, I used the raw latex as posted. But I'm not familiar with the lyx formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using LyX Version 2.3.2 and everything works fine. The only problem is that the line numbering starts at line 3 e.g. with \While{not converged}. Any hints how to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

LyX Version 2.3.4.3(Windows 10)
(14 February 2020)

1. **Insert->float->Algorithm**
2. Change **Environment choice box** (in this version it is just below file menu) from **Standard** to **LyX-code**
3. **Type the pseudo-code** inside the box as you would in an editor. Math formatting works as usual. To highlight keywords select text and press Ctrl+b.
   [image: An example.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
Insert > Program listing
then paste the code.