# Line numbering for all lines of pseudocode algorithm in Lyx

Tags: lyx, line-numbering, algorithmicx

I am trying to add an algorithm in pseudocode within LyX in version 2.3.2 as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212552/105873).

1. Add the `\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}` into the preamble
2. Insert a algorithm block (Insert --> Floating --> Algorithm)
3. Insert the tex code in the algorithm block (Insert --> Tex Code)
4. Add the following latex code

   ```
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \Require{$\rho \geq 1$}
   \Ensure{$X_k$}
   \While{not converged}
   \State{Solve $X_{k+1}=\min_{X} L(X,Y_k, \mu_k)$}
   \State{$Y_{k+1}=Y_k+\mu_k h(X_{k+1})$}
   \State{$\mu_{k+1}=\rho \mu_k$}
   \EndWhile
   \end{algorithmic}
   ```

Which delivers the following result:

[image]

According to other answers I have read, the `algorithmic[1]` command should number every line and not start at line 3 within the pseudocode.

How can I fix this and number all lines from the beginning e.g. starting from `\Require{$\rho \geq 1$}` in this example?

Comment: Technically the syntax is `\State abc`, not `\State{abc}`. Similarly for `\Require` and `\Ensure`.

Comment: Thans for clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not meant to have line numbers, but you can change that by adding the following to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble:

```
\algrenewcommand\Require{\State \algorithmicrequire~}%
\algrenewcommand\Ensure{\State \algorithmicensure~}%
```

The above updates `\Require` and `\Ensure` to be regular `\State`s and therefore set with a line number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!