# Adding line number to lyxcode environment in LyX

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX to typeset an algorithm containing math symbols. Following the [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212549/how-to-insert-algorithm-pseudocode-in-lyx), I could create an algorithm figure by Insert->Float->Algorithm and using LyX-code environment inside the box. But I could not find a way to add line numbers to the algorithm. How can I add line numbers to the LyX-code environment?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966661/insert-algorithm-in-lyx-2-1-1-with-line-numbers

Comment: I don't think this is a (cross-site) duplicate since it is specifically about "LyX-code" (this is the name of a specific environment), which that question does not address. @akarin64 have you considered using Insert > Program Listing. If you right-click on what that inserts and then go to settings, I think you can add line numbers to it. Would that work for you?

Comment: @scottkosty Sure, using Insert > Program Listing and applying line numbering worked, but it does not meet my requirement since I want to use equations inside the algorithm.

Comment: @akarin64 I see, that makes sense!